# C++: LinkedList Class Adds Empty Node as Head and Tail

Tags: c++, linked-list

i'm building a LinkedList Class to use as the base of a project. I've implemented the based LinkedList but have a weird bug that I cannot fix. Basically the head and tail of my list is always empty. Everything seems to work fine except for this weird problem. I have three files: a header which defines the node and list, an implementation file, and finally a file to run everything. can anyone spot my mistake? I think my error is in the add method.

header file:

```
class Node
{
    private:
        int data;
        Node *next;
        Node *prev;
        friend class LinkedList;
};

class LinkedList
{
    private:
        Node *head;
        Node *tail;

    public:
        LinkedList();
        ~LinkedList();

        bool empty();

        void insert_left(int v);
        void insert_right(int v);
        Node* get_first();
        Node* get_last();
        void print_list();
        void print_node(Node *n);
        void remove_left();
        void remove_right();


    protected:
        void add(Node *v, int d);
        void remove(Node *v);
};
```

class implementation file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "node.h"
using namespace std;

LinkedList :: LinkedList()
{
    head  = new Node;
    tail = new Node;

    head->next = tail;
    tail->prev = head;
}

LinkedList :: ~LinkedList()
{
    while(!empty())
    {
        remove_left();
    }
    delete head;
    delete tail;
}

void LinkedList :: add(Node *v, int d)
{
    Node *u = new Node;
    u->data = d;
    u->next = v;
    u->prev = v->prev;
    v->prev->next = v->prev = u;
}

void LinkedList :: insert_left(int v)
{
    /**
    if (head == NULL)
        add(head, v);
    else
        add(head->next, v);
    **/

    //add(head->prev,v);
    add(head->next,v);

}

void LinkedList :: insert_right(int v)
{
     add(tail,v);
}

void LinkedList :: remove(Node *v)
{
    Node *u = v->prev;
    Node *w = v->next;

    u->next = w;
    w->prev = u;

    delete v;
}

void LinkedList :: remove_left()
{
    remove(head->next);
}

void LinkedList :: remove_right()
{
    remove(tail->prev);
}

bool LinkedList :: empty()
{
    return (head->next == tail);
}

void LinkedList :: print_list()
{
    Node *tmp = head;
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
        cout << tmp->data << endl;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}

void LinkedList :: print_node(Node *n)
{
    Node *tmp = n;
    cout << tmp->data << endl;
}

Node* LinkedList :: get_first()
{
    return head;
}

Node* LinkedList :: get_last()
{
    return tail;
}
```

main file:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "list.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main(int agrc, char  **argv)
{
    LinkedList *l = new LinkedList();
    //LinkedList *m = new LinkedList();

    l->insert_left(200);
    l->insert_left(700);
    l->insert_left(300);

    //Node *temp = l->get_first();
    l->print_list();

    //l->print_node(temp);

    delete l;

    return 0;
}
```

after running main i get the following output which illustrates the problem:

```
0
300
700
200
0
```

Comment: You never set the head node or the tail node. You create them in the constructor, but your insert function isn't setting them.

Comment: It appears the block you have commented out in insert_left will do the right thing provided you set head to NULL in the constructor, and create it during the first insertion. Your tail should also be made to point to the head for the first insertion.

Answer (score 0):

1) In insert_left function use head instead of head->next.
2) In add() you have added new node to the left of head, so now your head should be updated.

```
head = u
```

3) head and tail are data members of your class then why you need to pass them across the functions. Use them directly.
Update your insert_left function like this

```
void LinkedList :: insert_left(int v)
{   
    Node *u = new Node;
    u->data = d;
    u->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {    
        head = u;
    }
    else
    {
         u->next = head;
         u->next->prev = u;
         head = u;
    }
}
```

Similarly you can modify your insert_right function using tail.